# RubyonRails MySQL select row column

Tags: ruby-on-rails

please a need a little help. I'm using a simple query in rails. But I would like to selecting the query in HAML, something like in PHP. Is this possible in rails?

Thanks for help.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "<br>";
    }

result_obj =  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select * from kiosk ")
@rows = []
index = 0
result_obj.each do |row|
@rows[index] = row
index += 1
```

HAML:

```
#@rows
```

Comment: Why are you not just using the model?

Comment: How about creating a model Kiosk and just `@rows = Kiosk.all`

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org is a must read for all starters in Rails.

Comment: PHP. the language that just won't die

Comment: I think you should know the ActiveRecord before using the rails.